# How to insert a new key and value in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Following is the output of my multidimensional array `$csmap_data`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cs_map_id] => 84
            [cs_subject_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cs_map_id] => 85
            [cs_subject_id] => 5
        )

    [flag] => 1
)
```

Initially there was no `[flag] => 1` key-value in the array, I added it to the array `$csmap_data`.
But I want to add the `[flag] => 1` in the above two array elements, not as a separate array element. In short I wanted following output :

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [cs_map_id] => 84
                [cs_subject_id] => 1
                [flag] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [cs_map_id] => 85
                [cs_subject_id] => 5
                [flag] => 1
            )
       )
```

The code I was trying to achieve this is as follows, but couldn't get the desired output:

```
if (!empty($csmap_data)) {  
                    foreach($csmap_data as $csm) {
                        $chapter_csmap_details = $objClassSubjects->IsClassSubjectHasChapters($csm['cs_map_id']);

                            $csmap_data ['flag'] = 1;


                    }
            }
```

Can anyone help me out in obtaining the desired output as I depicted? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Relevant advice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22640242/2943403

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
<?
 foreach($csmap_data as $key => $csm)
 {
  $csmap_data[$key]['flag'] = 1;
 }
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how can I do it without loop?

Answer (score 25):

You can also do it using php array functions

```
$csmap_data = array_map(function($arr){
    return $arr + ['flag' => 1];
}, $csmap_data);
```

UPDATE:
to use multiple variables in callback function of `array_map` function we can do it by `use`

```
$flagValue = 1;
$csmap_data = array_map(function($arr) use ($flagValue){
    return $arr + ['flag' => $flagValue];
}, $csmap_data);
```

Comment: How can i pass a variable to arraymap, suppose i have to pass varible insted of 1, is ther a way to do that

Comment: we can use "use"  to access other variables, we can also use global variables, also updated answer with "use"