# How to convert a 1-dimensional array into a 2-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array as follows:

```
$array['a'] = 'Red';
$array['b'] = 'Green';
$array['c'] = 'Blue';
```

I want to convert it to:

```
$array['a'][1] = 'Red';
$array['b'][1] = 'Green';
$array['c'][1] = 'Blue';
```

Is that possible with an existing PHP function or do I need to write my own function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20728171/convert-1d-array-to-2d-array-and-join-php
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18658475/converting-1d-array-to-a-2d-array-with-count-of-elements

Comment: maybe: array_walk($array, function(&$v, $k){ $v = array(1 => $v) })

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no built-in function that can achieve this. However, this is pretty straight-forward with a `foreach` loop, so I don't see why you need a function:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $result[$key][1] = $value;
}

print_r($result);
```

If you want a more functional approach, you could use [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/array_walk):

```
// walks through the original $array and adds a new dimension
array_walk($array, function(&$v, $k){ 
    $v = array(1 => $v); 
});
```

Although, a normal `foreach` would be more straight-forward and readable.

Comment: +1, though I'd add that the asker might want a function for code reuse purposes, or any of a number of other valid reasons.

Comment: @user1153551: And? That's the same as array in the OP's question :)